# String to variable substitution in sh

Tags: sh

is there an equivalent way of writing the following script using sh ? I can do it in bash, but need a sh version.

```
#!/bin/bash
REPOS="one two"
export onefirst="one_first"
export onelast="one_last"
export twofirst="two_first"
export twolast="two_last"

echo $onefirst
for name in $REPOS
do
        temp=${name}first
        echo ${!temp}  <--- bad substitution if I use sh
done
```

Output:

```
one_first
one_first
two_first
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need a plain sh version?

Comment: Use `eval`.  It's not evil.

Answer (score 1):

As chepner noted, you need eval. Slightly cleaner than his version: first construct the expression, then evaluate it:

```
echo again $onefirst
for name in $REPOS; do
    temp="\$${name}first" # Construct expression
    eval "echo $temp"     # Evaluate expression
done
```

This makes it easier to store the result of the evaluation without adding backslashes:

```
echo again $onefirst
for name in $REPOS; do
    temp="\$${name}first"    # Construct expression
    res=`eval "echo $temp"`  # Evaluate and store
    echo "$res"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish this in POSIX `sh` is to use `eval`, which means you need to be *very* sure that you know what the value of `temp` is before using it.

```
for name in $REPOS; do
  temp=${name}first
  eval "echo \"\$$temp\""  #  --> e.g. echo $onefirst
done
```